# Import GRD and count days with temperature below zero, using python

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

Minimum temperature of a year is given in GRD file. I have to read that file and then calculate the frost day (less than zero degrees celcius) from it in python.

Comment: Can you please provide I little bit more information (e.g. a sample file, a screenshot, or some numbers of your data).

Comment: sir,how can i send u sample file,there is no upload option.

Comment: (1) Is the data 365 days of temperature and you need to find how many are < 0? (2) You used the QGIS tag -- is your data imported already and you have questions about the statistics? Or are you asking about importing the GRD file?

Comment: yes sir,i am having the data of 365 days and want to calculate number of day in which temp is less than 0 degree celcius in python.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kru251hb8qyro7/MINT2005.GRD

Comment: If the grid file is in ASCII format, not binary, you can [use NumPy `loadtxt` to import the data into an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). However, your file seems to be binary and I'm not sure how to get that into Python.

Comment: I cannot open your sample file with GDAL or QGIS. You said you were able to open it in QGIS. Can you maybe save it as a GeoTIFF and upload it again

Comment: we can open and read the value of grd file in array form using python as:                                        import gdal
import struct
from gdalconst import *
#open the grd file 
ds = gdal.Open("MAXT2005.grd")
print ds
gdal.AllRegister() 
#read the 365 band
for i in range (1,ds.RasterCount):
 band=ds.GetRasterBand(i)
 #read the whole file into an array
 value=band.ReadAsArray( 0, 0, ds.RasterXSize, ds.RasterYSize)

Answer (score 2):

What are you using to do this?

In brief, you can load the data using [RasterIO](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/977) and then when you have a numpy array, you can do something like `numpy.where( data < 3 )` and [sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) the resulting fields. That should give you an array that is X by Y and has a single value, which is a count of the number of days that are sub-zero. RasterIO again has a write function.